# Table-Per-Type in EF Core 5, where inherited table PK has different column name than base table PK

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've scaffolded a database context from an existing database. The table has a base "Services" table. Depending on the type of service, it has additional information, stored in child tables ("BasicServices", "CustomServices").

Unfortunately, this existing schema was created in such a way that the child tables PK/FK column name doesn't match the base table's PK column name (the `Service` table uses `Id`, whereas the child tables use `ServiceId`)

If I ignore the mismatch in names, I get this:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'Id'.

If instead I specify that the child table's "Id" value comes from the column named "ServiceId"...

`entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ServiceId");`

I get this:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'ServiceId'.

I've read similar questions, and those are what lead me to trying the `HasColumnName()` solution, but in my case it didn't seem to work (or perhaps I misunderstood).

Any ideas?

---

**Database (SQL Server):**

```
dbo.Services
  Id (PK)
  Name

services.BasicServices
  ServiceId (PK, FK)
  BasicServiceExampleColumn

services.CustomServices
  ServiceId (PK, FK)
  CustomServiceExampleColumn
```

**Models:**

```cs
public partial class Service
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class BasicService : Service
{
    public string BasicServiceExampleColumn { get; set; }
}

public partial class CustomService : Service
{
    public string CustomServiceExampleColumn { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext:**

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BasicService>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("BasicServices", "services");
        //entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ServiceId");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomService>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("CustomServices", "services");
        //entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ServiceId");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<PackageService>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");
    });

    ...
}
```

Comment: It seems you didn't create a migration after configuring the `Id` property.

Comment: @Eldar Thanks for your reply. Given that this is a from-scratch implementation of EF Core that hasn't actually seen the light-of-day yet, is the migration necessary? Or can I just modify the code as it is right now?

Comment: There is never a need for migrations when you're mapping to an existing database.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't read the beginning of the question... You should also mention the name of the RDBMS you are using. Some require quotes for case-sensitive column names (like Oracle, Postgres etc)

Comment: Not possible currently in EF Core (including 6.0). There is only one PK property / column configuration and it is on the base class. All `HasCoumnName` override the name for the same base class property, and the last set wins.

Comment: @IvanStoev Eek, that's rough. I wonder if I can define a property named `ServiceId`  on the derived classes, whose getter/setter references `base.Id`...

Comment: No, you can't do that either. Sorry, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread with the same problem...
I found that I can't map the PK of a child class directly through the entity, but I managed to get around it by mapping through the table.

Inside each mapping, I replaced it

```
builder.ToTable("parent");
builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ID_OF_PARENT");

/* ... */

builder.ToTable("childOne");
builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ID_OF_CHILD_ONE");

/* ... */

builder.ToTable("childOTwo");
builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ID_OF_CHILD_TWO");
```

for it

```
builder.ToTable("parent", tb => tb.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ID_OF_PARENT"));

/* ... */

builder.ToTable("childOne", tb => tb.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ID_OF_CHILD_ONE"));

/* ... */

builder.ToTable("childTwo", tb => tb.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ID_OF_CHILD_TWO"));
```

In example above, `builder` is an `EntityTypeBuilder<>` and `tb` is a `TableBuilder<>` type. So we can map each child table.